# Contain form within a bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 240px;">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" rel="popover"
            data-content="<form><input type="text"/></form>"
            data-placement="top" data-original-title="Fill in form">Open form</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFmw8/)**

I'm guessing that I would store the form contents within a javascript function...

#### How do I contain a form within a bootstrap popover?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Either replace double quotes around `type="text"` within single quotes, Like:

```
"<form><input type='text'/></form>"
```

OR

Replace Double quotes wrapping `data-content` with single quote, Like:

```
data-content='<form><input type="text"/></form>'
```

Comment: don't forget the "data-html='true'" in the button tag

Comment: As of Bootstrap >= 3.4 you will also need {sanitize: false} as an initialisation option

Answer (score 278):

I would put my form into the markup and not into some data tag.
This is how it could work:

### JS Code:

```
$('#popover').popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: function() {
      return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
      return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

### HTML Markup:

```
<a href="#" id="popover">the popover link</a>
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">
  some title
</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <!-- MyForm -->
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/dzr521qs/)

### Alternative Approaches:

#### X-Editable

You might want to take a look at [X-Editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable).
 A library that allows you to create editable elements on your page based on popovers.

[image: X-Editable demo]

#### Webcomponents

Mike Costello has released [Bootstrap Web Components](https://github.com/MikeCostello/bootstrap-web-components). 
This nifty library has a Popovers Component that lets you embed the form as markup:

```
<button id="popover-target" data-original-title="MyTitle" title="">Popover</button>

<bs-popover title="Popover with Title" for="popover-target">
  <!-- MyForm -->
</bs-popover>
```

[Demo](http://mikecostello.github.io/bootstrap-web-components/)

Comment: Nice solution, I just put the title to `data-title="Some Title"` within the `<a id="myID">` tag for not having an extra div...

Comment: yepp thats right. The reason for this is that bootstrap won't cache the popover. Bootstrap removes it from the DOM when it closes. This restriction is therefore a problem of bootstrap.popover itself and not of this little hack.

Comment: If you want to persist the data, try to listen for the `hide.bs.popover` Event and then replace the `.popover-content` with the content from the popover. That might work.

Comment: Great answer. But i have one more question. how can I show tooltip at the bottom. According to the your sample, you are showing the tooltip at the right place... ???? Please help..

Comment: Thanks it workd. I have one more questions. when I click the other components tool tip is not hireing. I mean . when I cliecked empty area I want to close the opened tool tip... what can I do for that. which approach must I follow.

Comment: Please read: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers
You are looking for the `trigger` option. (`trigger: 'focus'`)

Comment: nice solution, but afaik `footer` can't be used which is defined in the html of your jsFiddle (which you don't resolve either)

Comment: is it possible to **bind** the content to the scope? The issue I'm facing is, that expressions defined within the html passed to `content` is not updated by angular

Comment: Why are you not using: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover?
It should solve your problems.

Answer (score 12):

```
<a data-title="A Title" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-content="<form><input type='text'/></form>" data-trigger="hover" rel="popover" class="btn btn-primary" id="test">Top popover</a>
```

> just state data-html="true"

Answer (score 5):

like this **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7e2XU/21/show/#
* Update: http://jsfiddle.net/kz5kjmbt/

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 240px;"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" rel="popover" data-content='
<form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Address 1 :</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>City :</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
 data-placement="top" data-original-title="Fill in form">Open form</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
    $('a[rel=popover]').popover({
      html: 'true',
      placement: 'right'
    })
```

*ScreenShot*

[image: working updated fiddle screenshot]

Comment: @DERIIIFranz Thanks its fixed now: http://jsfiddle.net/kz5kjmbt/ CDN gone missing, checkout updated link and screenshot. `:)`

Comment: This solution works on current Chrome and answers the question. However, having complex markups within html attributes may be error-prone and add risks on maintainability and learnability of the code.

Answer (score 5):

You can load the form from a hidden `div` element with the Bootstrap-provided `hidden` class.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="form-popover">Form popover</button>

<div class="hidden">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#form-popover').popover({
    content: $('#form').parent().html(),
    html: true,
});
```

Comment: Replace `$(...).parent().html()` with `$(...).clone()` ;)

Comment: If you clone, you could also use a `<template>` element instead of a hidden element.

Answer (score 3):

Or try this one

Second one including second hidden div content to hold the form working and test on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7e2XU/21/

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
   <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>


<div id="popover-content" style="display: none" >
    <div class="container" style="margin: 25px; ">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 240px;">
        <label id="sample">
            <form id="mainForm" name="mainForm" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Address 1 :</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>City :</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>

        </label>
    </div>
          </div> 
</div>

 <a href="#" style="margin: 40px 40px;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" rel="popover" data-content='' data-placement="left" data-original-title="Fill in form">Open form</a>


<script>

$('a[rel=popover]').popover({
    html: 'true',
placement: 'right',
content : function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
}
})



</script>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but your jsfiddle link does not seem to correspond to the same implementation. You find this plunk I made that implements it correctly: http://plnkr.co/edit/IV2YbLCFSiYI0T1mXOLN?p=preview.

Answer (score 2):

A complete solution for anyone that might need it, I've used this with good results so far

JS:

```
$(".btn-popover-container").each(function() {
    var btn = $(this).children(".popover-btn");
    var titleContainer = $(this).children(".btn-popover-title");
    var contentContainer = $(this).children(".btn-popover-content");

    var title = $(titleContainer).html();
    var content = $(contentContainer).html();

    $(btn).popover({
        html: true,
        title: title,
        content: content,
        placement: 'right'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-popover-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link popover-btn">Button Name</button>
    <div class="btn-popover-title">
        Popover Title
    </div>
    <div class="btn-popover-content">
        <form>
          Or Other content..
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-popover-container {
    display: inline-block;
}


.btn-popover-container .btn-popover-title, .btn-popover-container .btn-popover-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I work in WordPress a lot so use PHP.

My method is to contain my HTML in a PHP Variable, and then echo the variable in `data-content`.

```
$my-data-content = '<form><input type="text"/></form>';
```

along with

```
data-content='<?php echo $my-data-content; ?>'
```