# How do we stylize the heading and the content text in Bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, xhtml, css-frameworks

How do we stylize the heading and the content text in Bootstrap popover?

```
Click to toggle popover
```

I would like to have line breaks in the Popover title and content. Please help.

Comment: The popover has an option "html", which when turned on allows you to enter html content (won't be escaped). I am not sure if the same applies for the title.

Comment: Info here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question here: [Contain form within a bootstrap popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128425/contain-form-within-a-bootstrap-popover/12128784#12128784)

If you want to style the popover use some css:

```
.popover-title{
   /* insert your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks HaNdTriX, But how to make line breaks within Popover title and contents in the Bootstrap Popover.

Comment: Here is the solution adapted to your question http://jsfiddle.net/T43vV/ ! Use <BR> Tags...