# How to stop bootstrap popover form from disappearing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

following [Contain form within a bootstrap popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128425/contain-form-within-a-bootstrap-popover), I have managed to place a form within a popover which I'm using in my bootstrap navbar. The popup works fine when I hover over the link, but when I try to move the mouse to get to the popover form, it disappears ! How can I fix this?

Navbar Item:

```
<li <? if($active == "change_password") echo "class=\"active\""?>>
<?php echo '<a href="#" id="popover">the popover link</a>' ?>
</li>
<li class="divider-vertical"></li>
```

Here's the js:

```
$('li:contains("the popover link")').popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: function() {
        return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
        return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using a modal instead? That seems more suited to what you're attempting to do http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: do u have some event hover, mouseover, mousenter... on the element?

Comment: Thats a good idea - I'll check into the modal. Thanks - Bill

Answer (score 2):

You probably have this figured out or have a work around solution, but I wanted to share my solution since I needed the same thing and a modal wasn't optimal for the design. This works for both Bootstrap 2.x and 3.x and will maintain the toggling behavior with the click event.

```
$('li:contains("the popover link")').popover({
    html : true,
    title: function() {
        return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
        return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
}).mouseenter(function () {
    if (!$(this).parent().find('.popover').length) {
        $(this).popover('show');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mathachew/H5Jjk/)