# place a form within popover in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to place a form within popover in bootstrap 3?

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">Click It !</a>
```

it gives a effect like :

[image: pic]

I want to place a form within its body. How can we do it ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$('#popover').popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: function() {
      return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
      return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

Popover HTML Markup:

```
<a href="#" id="popover">the popover link</a>
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">some title</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <form>
    <!-- my form -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12128784/1035893

Answer (score 0):

I add content on popover like this:

```
$('#your-poped').popover({
  content: '<div id="preview"></div>',
  html: true,
  trigger: 'manual',
  delay: {'show':1000, 'hide':250},
});
$('#preview').html(yourdata);
```

Comment: delay showing and hiding the popover (ms) - does not apply to manual trigger type