# Bootstrap not setting popover template as expected

Tags: jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to customize the template used for the bootstrap popover. I found this...

```
$('.item').popover({
    html : true,
    placement: 'left',
    content: function(){
        return $(this).next('.our-popup').html();
    },
    template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
})
```

This works great! but now I want to make the template dynamic so I change to the following

```
template: $(this).next('.our-popup').next('.our-template').html();
```

I get an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
```

I also tried this...

```
template: function(){
  return $(this).next('.our-popup').next('.our-template').html();
}
```

And I get...

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document-fragment'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706896/place-a-form-within-popover-in-bootstrap-3) Not exactly the same so not marking as duplicate. Also I have put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwF7C/4/) for others

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#popover').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
  });
});
```