# Show a form-control input inside a Bootstrap Popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created a button with an Popover with a form-control inside. The popover works, but the content inside `data-content` is shown as a normal string. How can I change this?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
        data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"  
        title="Sort..." data-content='<input id="aaa" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search"/>'>

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span> sort
</button>
```

See this example on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lbRg28BomB).

Comment: See the following answer.
[Stack Overflow Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128425/contain-form-within-a-bootstrap-popover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `data-html='true'` to your popover button.

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://www.bootply.com/vtvIXLbc5e)