# Bootstrap popover only shows one word of string

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a set of popovers that show supplemental info upon hovering. They display, but only the first word of the string.

template:

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"  data-content={{std.Description}} >&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-question"></i></a>
...
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

The field in question is a Django `TextField`:

```
Description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Behavior:
[image]

This description had several words, but all after the first were cut off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is the same as for [Contain form within a bootstrap popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128425/contain-form-within-a-bootstrap-popover) , though the title of the post may be misleading. The issue is that there need to be quotes containing the desired variable:

```
data-content="{{std.Description}}"
```

Additionally, if you want to include html in the popover (lists, `<br>`, etc.), include `data-html="true"`.