# How to add buttons in Bootstrap 5 Popovers?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to put a button inside the `Popovers` in Bootstrap. But I did not succeed.

I am using Bootstrap-Popover. I want to have a button inside the popover.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 mb-3 servicePOP" data-aos="fade-up" tabindex="0" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="Title" data-bs-content="A short description">
    <div class="card position-relative">
        <div class="d-block card-icon">
            <img src="images.png" class="card-icon position-absolute start-0 end-0 m-auto rounded-circle mb-5 lazy" alt="Title">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body text-center mt-5 pt-5">
            <a href="# class="text-decoration-none text-dark">
                <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
            </a>
            <p>A short description</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    let servicePOP = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Test link</a>';
    $('.servicePOP').popover({
        content: servicePOP,
        html: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your answers was well clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519005/20836041) . Look the [HTML option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options) in bootstrap page

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sanitize: false` option to `popover`

Comment: How to add `sanitize: false` option to `popover`? Can you send complete codes?

Comment: Yes only add sanitize: false to popover